# Most effective way to reflect inheritance relationship in DAOs?

Tags: java, inheritance, crud, dao, business-objects

Working on a business application using MVC structure and a [Business Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object) / [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)  architecture.  For any normal business object, the CRUD functions are fairly straightforward.  But what's the best way to handle a parent-child relationship like "Customer is a User"?

I know that the following classes are involved:

```
User, UserDAO, Customer, CustomerDAO
```

The `Customer` class can inherit from the `User` just fine, but how do you best reflect this in the DAO CRUD functions?

Comment: Do you have two tables -- `Users` and `Customers`? I would be surprised. I would think a `users` table with a `user_type` field. And then have only one VO i.e. `Users`. And if `user.isCustomer()` true, it's customer. So, either you should not use two tables or you should not use inheritance.

Comment: @Nishant:  That's not true at all.  If Customers have additional data that Users do not, you are going to be cluttering up the User table with irrelevant columns.  It is certainly feasible to implement inheritance with two tables.

Comment: @Matt I am not speaking on feasibility, I was more thinking on design. Customer is a User -- and it's good idea to have both of them in same table. It will help in searching plus makes more sense to me. If you are worried about cluttering, externalize the extraneous data. Make a separate table `customer_details` and link it with foreign key. In many scenario, you may want to convert a user into a customer. It's easier to just change the type instead of copying the data between tables then erasing the former. Just my 2%.

Comment: @user456584: http://blogs.tedneward.com/2006/06/26/The+Vietnam+Of+Computer+Science.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Martin Fowler has documented a few [Object-Relational Structural Patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) that might help:

1) [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html): Represents an inheritance hierarchy of classes as a single table that has columns for all the fields of the various classes.

e.g. `Employee` and `Customer` both inherit from `User` and are both stored in the User table, with a column that determines what type of user a particular record represents.

2) [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html): Represents an inheritance hierarchy of classes with one table for each class.

e.g. `Employee` and `Customer` both inherit from `User` and there are three tables to represent this.  The User table stores the properties common to all users.  The Employee table has a pointer to the User table and only stores the properties relevant to Employees.  The same is true of the Customer table.

3) [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html): Represents an inheritance hierarchy of classes with one table per concrete class in the hierarchy.

e.g. `Employee` and `Customer` both inherit from the abstract `User` class and there are two tables to represent this.  A Customer table and an Employee table.  Each table stores information common to users, but also stores unique properties.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. So, I'm using #2. Any thoughts about how to best implement CRUD functions for Employee/Customer/User under Class Table Inheritance?

Comment: Glad you found this post helpful! I like Matt's idea of wrapping the UserDAO inside of the CustomerDAO.

Answer (score 7):

You can have an instance of UserDAO in CustomerDAO.  You need to interact with both the User and Customer tables to cover the base class and subclass columns.  For example:

```
public class CustomerDAO
{
    UserDAO userDao;

    // ... initialization ...

    public void update(Customer customer)
    {
        // ... first execute update of customer table ...

        userDao.update(customer);   // Should be able to pass Customer to UserDAO due to inheritance
    }

    public void insert(Customer customer)
    {
        // First insert a row in the User table so that the ID of the user can be determined.
        userDao.insert(customer);

        // ... Now execute insertion of row into Customer table ...
    }

    public void delete(Customer customer)
    {
        // ... first delete Customer row ...

        // Now delete base class User row.
        userDao.delete(customer);
    }
}
```

Of course, each Customer operation should probably be wrapped in a transaction so that updating the User and Customer tables does not fail independently.